# Evaluating objects containing Strings with Java ArrayList contains()

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to do a deeper String check of Objects to be able to do the following:

```
List<MyObj> myList = new ArrayList<MyObj>() {{
    add(new MyObj("hello"));
    add(new MyObj("world"));
}};

System.out.println(myList.contains("hello")); // true
System.out.println(myList.contains("foo")); // false
System.out.println(myList.contains("world")); // true
```

But getting false on each one with the following full code

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
    public static class MyObj {
        private String str;
        private int hashCode;

        public MyObj(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        public @Override boolean equals(Object obj) {
            System.out.println("MyObj.equals(Object)");
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }

            if (obj instanceof String) {
                String strObj = (String) obj;
                return strObj.equals(str);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public @Override int hashCode() {
            if (hashCode == 0) {
                hashCode = 7;
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
                    hashCode = hashCode * 31 + str.charAt(i);
                }
            }

            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public static final MyObj obj1 = new MyObj("hello");
    public static final MyObj obj2 = new MyObj("world");
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List<MyObj> myList = new ArrayList<MyObj>() {{
            add(obj1);
            add(obj2);
        }};

        System.out.println(myList.contains("hello"));
        System.out.println(myList.contains("foo"));
        System.out.println(myList.contains("world"));
    }
}
```

If I'm right the List Object should use `equals()` and `hashCode()` to evaluate containing Objects.
So I `@Override` them and check their Strings additionally.
But it never gets into `equals()` as there's no output `MyObj.equals(Object)`.

Comment: Your list contains `MyObj` instances, not `String` instances.

Comment: It's not possible, java is a strong type language. You need MyObj instances

Comment: Your code working correctly.  **new MyObj("hello") != hello**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`java.util.ArrayList#indexOf` is used internally in ArrayList for `contains()`.

There is a check,

```
o.equals(elementData[i])
```

So there is comparison of string with your object, so `String.equals()` is invoked for check of equality.

Answer (score 5):

You are not fulfilling the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) contract at all:

The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:

- It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true. **Yours is not reflexive**.
- It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true. **Yours is not symmetric.**
- It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true. **Yours is not transitive**
- It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
- For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

So without respecting the contract for the method you can't expect intended behavior.

**Just for example, what guarantees you that equals is going to be called on the object contained in the ArrayList and not in the other way, eg `"hello".equals(new MyObj("hello"))`. You have no guarantees about it but since `equals` is normally supposed to be symmetric than you shouldn't mind.**

Comment: This answer is more detailed about why it isn't working. But I think Admits answer is more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, the problem is that *your* equals method is never called. When you invoke `myList.contains("hello")`, `ArrayList` checks whether `"hello".equals(<MyObj>)`, not the other way around.

Instead, I recommend implementing your `equals` method *properly*, so that two `MyObject` instances with equal `value` are considered equal, and then create a helper method like this:

```
public boolean myContains(List<MyObj> list, String value) {
    return list.contains(new MyObj(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyObj> myList = new ArrayList<MyObj>()
```

is a list of `MyObj`, so you need to use `MyObj` while checking `myList.contains`:

```
System.out.println(myList.contains(new MyObj("hello")));
System.out.println(myList.contains(new MyObj("foo")));
System.out.println(myList.contains(new MyObj("world")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the List to compare a `String` to a `MyObj`... They are never going to be "equal". Try a map instead:

```
Map<String, MyObj> map = new HashMap<String, MyObj>() {{
    put("hello", new MyObj("hello"));
    put("world", new MyObj("world"));
}};
```

Then you can use:

```
if (map.containsKey("hello"))
```

and to get the corresponding object:

```
MyObj o = map.get("hello"); // get() returns null if key not found
```

Comment: Nice idea, but we do not know whether it fits his use case. E.g., maybe it has to be ordered, or he gets the lists from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Doesn`t fit my use case. But nice idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not equals of your object called when contains executes but the one from String class.
And String implementation checks with instanceof whether the class is a String to perform String-like operations to determine the answer. If object is not a String it will return false;